# Why isn't logistic regression learning the correct weights for a Y variable defined as logit of X and weights?

Tags: logistic, classification, python, statsmodels

I am trying to see if the implementation of logistic regression in my is correct. In order to do that I first started to generate some random X data and specify some predefined weights.

When I train the model using a standard implementation of Logistic regression the model doesn't learn the correct pre-specified weights. Am I doing something wrong in my implementation.

Here what my code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

X = sm.add_constant(np.random.randn(1000,3)*10)
w = np.array([0.25, 0.1, 0.3, -1.5])

def logit(x):
    return 1. / (1. + np.exp(x))

y = logit(np.dot(X,w) + np.random.randn(X.shape[0])*0.0001) # y ~ logit(X.w + Random Noise)
model = sm.Logit(y>0.5, X) # Label y as 1 if y > 0.5 else 0
res = model.fit()
print res.summary2()
```

Here is the output I get from my model:

```
Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 35
                          Results: Logit
==================================================================
Model:              Logit            Pseudo R-squared: 1.000      
Dependent Variable: y                AIC:              8.0000     
Date:               2016-02-21 18:08 BIC:              27.6310    
No. Observations:   1000             Log-Likelihood:   -6.5515e-06
Df Model:           3                LL-Null:          -692.70    
Df Residuals:       996              LLR p-value:      4.3502e-300
Converged:          0.0000           Scale:            1.0000     
No. Iterations:     35.0000                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------
           Coef.    Std.Err.    z    P>|z|     [0.025     0.975]  
------------------------------------------------------------------
const     -28.4569 1024.9463 -0.0278 0.9779  -2037.3148  1980.4009
x1        -13.8000  411.2444 -0.0336 0.9732   -819.8241   792.2242
x2        -40.6588 1204.5892 -0.0338 0.9731  -2401.6104  2320.2927
x3        201.4672 5953.2122  0.0338 0.9730 -11466.6144 11869.5488
==================================================================
```

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the model learn the coefficients as the weights I specified above ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not simulating a Bernoulli experiment. 
Also, your y can be perfectly predicted and there should be a perfect prediction warning or exception.

If I change to a Bernoulli experiment, and increase the sample size so the estimate is closer to the true values, and add a seed for replicability, then I get a good match.

I think your Logit function has the opposite sign from what is used in statsmodels, i.e. it uses zeros as the "success" case.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

np.random.seed(12345)
X = sm.add_constant(np.random.randn(20000,3)*10)
w = np.array([0.25, 0.1, 0.3, -1.5])

def logit(x):
    return 1. / (1. + np.exp(x))

y = logit(np.dot(X,w))
from scipy import stats
#yo = stats.bernoulli.rvs(y, size=y.shape[0])   # opposite sign
yo = 1 - stats.bernoulli.rvs(y, size=y.shape[0])
model = sm.Logit(yo, X)
res = model.fit()
print res.summary()
```

which produces

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.084227
         Iterations 11
                         Results: Logit
================================================================
Model:              Logit            Pseudo R-squared: 0.878    
Dependent Variable: y                AIC:              3377.0925
Date:               2016-02-21 21:23 BIC:              3408.7065
No. Observations:   20000            Log-Likelihood:   -1684.5  
Df Model:           3                LL-Null:          -13858.  
Df Residuals:       19996            LLR p-value:      0.0000   
Converged:          1.0000           Scale:            1.0000   
No. Iterations:     11.0000                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------
         Coef.    Std.Err.      z       P>|z|     [0.025    0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------
const    0.2499     0.0446     5.6100   0.0000    0.1626    0.3373
x1       0.1007     0.0050    20.2428   0.0000    0.0909    0.1104
x2       0.2964     0.0085    34.6648   0.0000    0.2796    0.3131
x3      -1.5137     0.0373   -40.5711   0.0000   -1.5868   -1.4405
================================================================
```

**addition**  expanding on comments

The underlying data generating process of Logit and many other link functions for Bernoulli experiments can also be represented by a *latent* variable and a observation equation that limits what can be observed of the latent variable.

As dsaxton pointed out in the comment, the distribution of the latent variable is the logistic distribution.

I think the Python code is self explanatory:

```
np.random.seed(987654)

linpred = np.dot(X,w)
r = stats.logistic.rvs(size=X.shape[0])    
y = linpred + r  # latent variable
yo = y >= 0  # observed binary variable

model = sm.Logit(yo, X)
res = model.fit()
print res.summary2()
```

The estimated parameters are (I adjusted the seed a bit to get a "nice" random draw.)

```
>>> print(res.params)
[ 0.26791279  0.09486941  0.30443008 -1.49688738]
```

The latent variable formulation is often used in econometrics because it easily generalized to, for example, truncated models like Tobit or ordered Logit or Probit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about the sampling from Bernoulli process part. My code work now.

BTW, why is it is that sampling from Bernoulli distribution is different from using Y > 0.5, isn't that is what we do when we do the prediction step ?

Comment: There is an equivalent `latent variable` formulation that is additive in the linear prediction part but adds an error term in a different distribution. Adding a normal error would create a Probit sample. For the Logit, the distribution of the error term is the extreme value distribution, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @user333700 I think you're referring to the complementary log-log link, which comes from the Gumbel distribution.  The logit is the inverse distribution function (quantile function) for a logistic random variable.

Comment: @dsaxton Thanks for the correction. Using logistic `scipy.stats.logistic` directly works in the example. What I didn't remember or mixed up is that in the discrete choice literature the choice specific error is extreme value distributed, but the Logit comes from the difference of two extreme value or gumbel distributed random variables. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution#Related_distributions

Answer (score 3):

First a minor terminology thing, but the function you've defined is actually called the sigmoid and not the logit, which is the *inverse* of the sigmoid function.  Secondly you're missing a minus sign and it should instead be $1 / (e^{- w^T x} + 1)$.

Most importantly you're adding an error term to the sigmoid when there is no such thing in logistic regression.  The way you should generate $Y_i$ is by sampling from a Bernoulli distribution with $1 / (e^{- w^T x_i} + 1)$ as the success probability.  If you do this then you should get the right estimates in your simulation.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is in your "logit" definition (which is really the logistic function, the inverse of logit): it should be $exp(-x)$, not $exp(x)$.